# Using map() on a _set in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two models like this:

```
class KPI(models.Model):
    """KPI model to hold the basic info on a Key Performance Indicator"""
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    target = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(KpiGroup)
    subGroup = models.ForeignKey(KpiSubGroup, null=True)
    unit = models.TextField(blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bt_measure = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class KpiHistory(models.Model):
    """A historical log of previous KPI values."""
    kpi = models.ForeignKey(KPI)
    measure = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    kpi_date = models.DateField()
```

and I'm using [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/) to display the stats on internal wallboards, the handy thing is Python lists get output in a format that Javascript sees as an array, so by mapping all the values into a list like this:

```
def f(x): return float(x.measure)
stats = map(f, KpiHistory.objects.filter(kpi=1)
```

then in the template I can simply use

```
{{ stats }}
```

and the RGraph code sees it as an array which is exactly what I want.

```
[87.0, 87.5, 88.5, 90]
```

So my question is this, is there any way I can achieve the same effect using Django's _set functionality to keep the amount of data I'm passing into the template, up until now I've been passing in a single KPI object to be graphed but now I want to pass in a whole bunch so is there anything I can do with _set

```
{{ kpi.kpihistory_set }}
```

dumps the whole model out, but I just want the measure field.

I can't see any of the built in template methods that will let me pull out just the single field I want.

How have other people handled this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing the logic to decide which instances should be shown in a particular request in the view function, rather than in the template.

Comment: I am, I select the KPI in the view. I want it's corresponding KpiHistory records to be available as a list, but just the values, not the whole model, similar to the result when I use a map function now.

Comment: so set the result of the map as a template context variable in the view.

Comment: When I have a whole bunch of these KPIs that I want to display, it doesn't feel especially efficient to send the info twice (once in the model & once in the list) I use other info from the model too, I was hoping there was a better way of doing it.